# Query to find Single Entry from the Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have a Question where i Have One table as Follows:

```
from_city  to_city      Distance
bangalore  chennai      350
chennai    Bangalore    350
mumbai     bangalore    500
bangalore  Mumbai       500
Mumbai     Delhi        500
Delhi      Mumbai       500
```

Here i sould get an answer as follows:

```
bangalore  chennai     350
Mumbai     Bangalore   500
Mumbai     Delhi       500
```

the answer can bangalore-chennai or channai-bangalore.since its same distance on both ways. I need only one entry from each cities. how can i achieve it? the answer should be general. tommorrrow if  some other cities are added like bangalore -mysore or mysore-bangalore,I need only entry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using distinct with case:

```
select distinct
  case when lower(from_city) < lower(to_city) 
        then Initcap(from_city) else Initcap(to_city) end as from_city,
  case when lower(from_city) < lower(to_city) 
        then Initcap(to_city) else Initcap(from_city) end as to_city,
  Distance
from t;
```

Produces:

```
FROM_CITY   TO_CITY     DISTANCE
--------------------------------
Delhi       Mumbai      500
Bangalore   Mumbai      500
Bangalore   Chennai     350
```